# How to mirror a pose for a keyframe (ctrl c + shift ctrl v not working)

Tags: animation, keyframes, mirror, pose-mode

This is probably a pretty noob question, but I can't get the pose to mirror. I'm making a running/walking animation for my character. I'm at the half way point, where the left leg and the right leg are just about to cross (left leg becomes the front leg, and right leg becomes the back leg).

I looked up how to mirror a pose, and I tried out the ctrl c + ctrl shift v to flip it over the x axis, but the pose ends up really funky, with joints bent backwards and such. I got what I needed by doing ctrl m + x. But when I do that, it mirrors the whole animation, not just the pose for that keyframe.

How can I mirror just that one keyframe, or do something that achieves the same effect?

Comment: Not an answer, but I recommend watching Imphenzia's tutorials on character rigging, particularly these:  

[Model and rig characters...][1]
[Armature rigging...][2]
[Simple Walk Cycle][3]

His explanations are straightforward, and I followed several of his tutorials with good results for rigging walk cycles, including the flipped mirror poses.

Pay particular attention to the initial rigging and bone rolls, as they are key to the mirror poses working properly.

  [1]: https://youtu.be/TZDnV4KshM8
  [2]: https://youtu.be/pkuOs_VA_y4
  [3]: https://youtu.be/B5h2HvkqXZ0

Comment: Thank you, that seems to fix the problem. I think it had something to do with how I mirrored the armature using the .L and .R.

Comment: Glad it worked out.  The series of steps he shows is complicated, but reliable. If you don't do it regularly, (like I don't,) it's easy to skip a step.

Comment: Try to select both sides, the last one is the one you want to mirror. Everything should work